# Account login audit and track activities

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are having a problem and need to track user steps.

We look at Stackdrive and it doesn't have the information we need.
At https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity, it shows the activities of the year 2018.
I need to see a user's activities. When he connected, what did he do.
But there were activities that year. Could it have been deleted?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Stackdriver does not record information such as a user logging into a Compute Engine instance via SSH. This can be enabled by setting up Stackdriver to log the SSH server authorization log file. This file also records sudo/root commands executed by users. Normal unprivileged commands are not recorded by this method. That requires add-ons.

The data might still be present on the instance:

`/var/log/auth.log`

Also, check for rollover log files such as `/var/log/auth*`

If you have enabled or created snapshots, you can restore those snapshots and pull the data from past events.

Comment: Hi.Sorry for the delay.
I need the events from the Google Admin console, not the virtual machines.
Stackdriver is not showing these logs.

Comment: @Christovam - That requires that Audit Logging is enabled to record these types of events. Did you enable it? I am assuming that you did not, therefore there are no records for you to lookup.

Comment: Hi! Does Audit Logging show this information? 


4:00 pm  Done: Patch the firewall rule  c****@gmail.com patched default-allow-ssh
4:00 pm Patch the firewall rule c****@gmail.com patched default-allow-ssh
08:48 Completed: Start VM c*****@gmail.com started VM instance-1

Comment: @Christovam Google has good documentation on Audit Logging with example output.